# Problems installing ubuntu 12.10 alongside windows 8

Tags: 12.04, boot, uefi, windows-8

I can't install ubuntu on my computer (Asus ux31 with windows 8), the primary reason is that I cannot boot from any usb device with the new windows called "uefi".

Do you guys have an solution for this?

I apreciate the help!

Comment: what do you mean by *cannot boot any usb*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.04 using UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/135621/ubuntu-12-04-using-uefi)

Answer (score 2):

First, UEFI is not a "new Windows;" it's a new *firmware* that's in the process of replacing the 30-year-old BIOS. See [the Wikipedia article on UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uefi) for details.

There are a number of possible causes for your problem. The easiest one to solve is that you simply need to select the boot device using a boot menu. On my ASUS P8H77-I motherboard, this menu can be accessed by pressing F8 as the computer starts up. (As soon as you power on, start repeatedly tapping F8.) It's possible you'll need to use another key, though. Using it should produce a boot menu that gives you boot options. If you have trouble getting the menu, try again; it can be finicky. Be sure to select the boot option for your USB drive that includes the string "UEFI" or "EFI," otherwise you're likely to install in BIOS mode, which will cause further problems down the line.

Another possibility is that your problem is with a specific UEFI feature called *Secure Boot.* Microsoft is requiring computers that bear a Windows 8 logo to ship with Secure Boot enabled, but this blocks other OS installations. Linux distribution maintainers have announced plans to work around this obstacle, but I don't know offhand if they were implemented in time for Ubuntu 12.10's release. If not, you'll need to do something about it yourself. The only practical solution at the moment is to disable Secure Boot in your computer's firmware. To do this, you'll need to enter the setup utility, locate the option, and disable it. On my ASUS P8H77-I motherboard, you'd press Del during the boot process to enter the setup utility. Once in, pressing F7 enters Advanced mode, which is necessary to get at the options. Enter the Boot menu and select the Security Boot Parameters option, which reveals additional options to enable or disable Secure Boot. My motherboard shipped with Secure Boot disabled, so I'm not sure exactly what you'll see, but my hunch is you'd want to change OS Type from Windows 8 UEFI to Other Legacy & UEFI. Of course, all this assumes that you'll see the same menus in your ASUS UX31 computer as I see in my ASUS P8H77-I motherboard. That's not really a safe assumption; you may need to improvise. In the future, major distributions will ship with installers and boot loaders that will work with Secure Boot, and additional boot loader programs will exist to help work around the trouble that this feature causes. (Note that Secure Boot has real potential to solve some security problems, particularly in Windows 8. Although conspiracy theories abound concerning Secure Boot, I'm unconvinced by them.)